# Where are the styles for webkit-appearance coming from?

Tags: css, safari, webkit, mobile-safari, appearance

I understand the basic idea behind the `-webkit-appearance` property and how it applies platform-native styling to an element. But I don't understand where these platform-native styles are defined. I thought they might be in the user agent stylesheet but there are no styles present that make, for example, the `<input type="date" />` look like this in mobile Safari:

[image]

[You can view the user agent stylesheet of Safari here](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) which does not include (as far as I know) styles that make an input with the type of date render like the above image.

It appears the most of the styling is done through a single CSS property within the user agent stylesheet, which is:

```css
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
```

This drastically changes the visual output of the input on mobile Safari to look like the example image.

Where are these styles coming from if not from the user agent stylesheet?

Comment: will you please share the link or code so that i and other look into it to provide better solution

Comment: Sure thing, I've added a link, it's a simple scenario.

Comment: this is default, so can overwrite it by your own css like '-webkit-appearance: none;'

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't answer my original question. I'm not looking to overwrite it, I'm trying to figure out the location of where these default styles are defined.

Comment: Yes you can overwrite it, as i provide you the css code, there are some default properties on html elements that we see in browser, it is one of them

Comment: Of course that comes from the user agent stylesheet. Not sure what you even mean by _“but that is where webkit-appearance itself is declared”_ here.

Comment: @04FS I'm mean the styles that make the `<input type="date" />` look like a button with a dropdown in mobile Safari are not in the user agent stylesheet (as far as I know, [view it here](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css#L467)).

The CSS property `-webkit-appearance: menulist-button` is defined in the user agent stylesheet and appears to be the reason the `<input type="date" />` looks the way it is in the provided screen shot but these specific styles that make it look like a button with dropdown do not exist in the user agent style sheet.

Comment: @04FS, I found the answer to this issue if you're curious, posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigating and digging into the Webkit source code, I found the answer.

In the context of Webkit based browsers, elements that have an `appearance` CSS property applied to them **do not** receive their **platform-native styles** from the browser's user agent stylesheet. These styles are defined outside of the UA stylesheet in a `renderTheme` file which is part of the internals of the Webkit engine.

For example, you can find the styles I was asking for in my original question being defined here: https://trac.webkit.org/browser/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderThemeIOS.mm#L623

To break this all down: in mobile Safari, an `<input type="date" />` receives `-webkit-appearance: menulist-button` from the user agent stylesheet of Safari. The additional styling applied by `-webkit-appearance: menulist-button` which **is not** in the user agent stylesheet [is defined within a `renderTheme` file of Webkit.](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderThemeIOS.mm#L623)